# Awesome window manager on startup

Tags: awesome

I've installed Awesome window manager on Ubuntu 12-04

I have followed these [instructions](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Ubuntu_11.10) to set it up. It works correctly.

I am now trying to add some shell commands to be run at startup. [swapping mouse buttons round & stopping the display turning off when idle]. I have these commands stored in the **.xsession** file and I have **.xinitrc** sym linked to .xsession.

The commands in **.xsession** are not being executed. How can I make these commands run? Are they in the wrong place?

I thought awesome was an extension to Xwindows and so it would run ~/.xsession when it starts up. But it isn't doing.

```
andy@:~$ cat ~/.xsession
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"

setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
xset s off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts in home folder results in race conditions with others if not taken care of...

I suggest to have these commands in some place say `/usr/local/bin/awesome-personal` script.

So create a file called `/usr/local/bin/awesome-personal` and the contents of it being:

```
#Assuming the awesome binary file is /usr/bin/awesome

xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"

setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0 <br />
xset s off

exec /usr/bin/awesome
```

Now copy the global xsession file /usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop (to save the original copy) by running the command:

```
cp /usr/share/xsessions/{awesome.desktop,awesome2.desktop}
```

Now start editing the `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome2.desktop` file and replace

```
Exec=/usr/bin/awesome
```

with:

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/awesome-personal
```

Things should work now. On starting Ubuntu, you can select the personal `awesome` window manager by selecting the new entry `awesome2` session. (You can select it from the lightdm where you enter the password while logging in ubuntu).

If it still doesn't work, comment back here...

Comment: thanks. - If I move the 'exec /usr/bin/awesome' to the last part of the script it works