# Replacing Nautilus with Awesome Windows Manager on 12.04

Tags: window-manager, window

Just like the title suggests, any idea on replacing nautilus with Awesome WM?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused. Awesome WM, as the name says, its a complete window manager. On its side, Nautilus is a file manager. Anyways, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163215/awesome-window-manager-on-startup) can be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) are those programs which provide the windowing functionality, such as title bar, window border, moving, resizing etc. And [Awesome is a window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29), which is lightweight in resource usage.

On the other hand, a [File manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) is a program which provides you facility to browse or navigate the file system, move, copy, create files etc. And [Nautilus falls in the category of file managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager), it's not a window manager. In fact, Nautilus is the most loved and used file manager in Linux desktops.

There cannot be any question of replacing a window manager with a file manager. But, yes, you could ask to replace [Compiz (which is another window manager)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz)  with awesome window manager or replace nautilus with another file manager such as [Thunar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar).

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use other file manager such as PCManFM or Dolphin in Awesome WM. And there is also a file manager in terminal like Ranger.